# passing multiple views in a single template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

is there a possibilty of passing multiple views into a single template, this is because just one on view seems to be passing through the and the other doesnt come up, here's my piece of code for better understanding

views:

```
def post_detail(request):
seconds = Second.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:4]
return render(request,'home/feature.html',{'seconds': seconds})



def post_list(request):
posts = First.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:4]
return render(request,'home/marketing.html',{'posts': posts})
```

and my urls is thus:

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
 url(r'^$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Comment: And where is the view that renders that template? Does it pass `posts`? (Note, this is probably not Jinja but Django template language.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman, i just edited my question..thanks

Comment: But you've got two views there at the same URL. That can't work. Only the ListView will ever be called.

Comment: @DanielRoseman,  could you please give me a lead example so I could follow up from there.. thanks